# Connect to Teradata: difference between a regular and a domain user

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jdbc, teradata

I did write code

```
import jaydebeapi

USERNAME="user01"
PASSWORD="password01"
URL_CONNECTION="jdbc:teradata://server01/"
jars=['E:\\jdbc\\tdgssconfig.jar','E:\\jdbc\\terajdbc4.jar']

conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver', URL_CONNECTION,[USERNAME,PASSWORD], jars)
```

If I post username and password User protected internal password - OK.
BUT if I post  username and password by LDAP returned error

```
jpype._jexception.SQLExceptionPyRaisable: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.10.00.07] [Error 8017] [SQLState 28000] The UserId, Password or Account is invalid.
```

Is exist difference between internal user and LDAP user? That I have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your URL_CONNECTION to include the LOGMECH parameter to specify LDAP.

```
import jaydebeapi

USERNAME="user01"
PASSWORD="password01"
URL_CONNECTION="jdbc:teradata://server01/LOGMECH=LDAP"
jars=['E:\\jdbc\\tdgssconfig.jar','E:\\jdbc\\terajdbc4.jar']

conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver', URL_CONNECTION,[USERNAME,PASSWORD], jars)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the logon mechanism as LDAP in Teradata for it to be authenticating you via LDAP. By default, Teradata goes for TD2 authentication mechanism and that is why your internal password works and not LDAP.

Comment: How change type authentication mechanism in python script?